# Javascript regular expression syntax

Tags: javascript

How would this be done in Javascript?

```
strCellID.Replace(Regex.Match(strCellID, @"(?<=_m)\d+(?=_l)").Value, "-");
```

Answer (score 4):

That regular expression uses a look-behind assertion and those aren't supported in JavaScript.  You could use sub-expression captures to achieve the same result, though:

```
// $1 references the first captured sub-expression 
strCellID.replace(/(_m)\d+(?=_l)/g, "$1-");
```

See also:

- [replace() - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Regular Expressions - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @user517406: There's nothing wrong with the syntax, the regex parses just fine.  *Doesn't seem to work* isn't a very good description of a problem.  However, I'd guess that you're probably not assigning the result to anything - strings are immutable so `replace()` will not change the original string, it will return a new string containing the result instead.  If you put a `strCellID = ` in front of the line of code I gave you, it would solve that particular problem.  If that's not your problem, you'll need to be more specific.  Maybe you could provide some input and expected output samples?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I had.  If I wanted to do something like this                                                          `code`newCellID = newCellID.replace(/(_l)\d+(?=_o)/g, "$1" + msg.d); `code`                                                        would I be able to use the same syntax?

Comment: @user: yeah, there's no reason that wouldn't work (assuming your `msg` object is set up correctly).

Comment: Tried it and the replace doesn't happen i.e. the string remains in it's original state.  I have tried both with msg.d and after converting msg.d to a string

Comment: @user517406: you'd have to show more code, I'm afraid.  If the string returned is the same as the original string it indicates that no matches were found, or the replacement string is exactly the same as the content being replaced.  I would check your input string first.  `msg.d` is converted to a string automatically by the `+` concatenation operator.

Comment: msg.d is a numeric value...by concatenating $1 and msg.d if msg.d is for example 250, this will create a string $1250, will appending $1 with a numeric cause problems?

Comment: @user: ah, yes, that is the problem and that scenario didn't cross my mind.  Instead of `"$1" + msg.d`, try `"$01" + msg.d`.  Otherwise the regex method is trying to replace with capture `$12`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: "$01" is giving the same result as "$1" ie the original string does not change